# Deplying django and vue don't load the site

Tags: django, vue.js, deployment

Im trying to deploy django with the dist folder generated from the `npm run build` command, I tested the site with the serve npm package and works just fine, but when I copy that folder into the django project directory and run `python manage.py runserver` the page renders blank and the browser console tells these errors.

`The resource from “http://localhost:8000/assets/index-422b98df.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`

and

`Loading module from “http://localhost:8000/assets/index-4435c3df.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

I just wrote the simplest view to render the index.html.

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'dist/index.html')
```

Any help will be useful, thanks in advance.

Comment: The “text/html” is indicating you are likely throwing errors when trying to serve those assets. Visit one of those urls directly in your browser and you will likely see what the error is. (Or look at the response in the Network tab of your browser’s dev tools area.)